# Feign Client and Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, netflix-feign

I am trying to use a @FeignClient with Redis but Redis needs to serialize the Client bean to use it in the session. If I make the Client object transient then it becomes null after the first use.

If I make it transient, I have to take it from the Application Context everytime I use it, which is bad practice.

Is there a good way to serialize the Feign Client so that I can use it along with Redis or is this a bad idea in the first place?

**Edit:**

I used a [serializable proxy library](https://github.com/chelu/jdal/tree/master/aop) on the feign client and have made everything a spring component with a UIScope.

If this solution doesn't seem correct, please announce me! :)

Comment: You can answer your own question. So instead of adding the answer in an edit section in your question, you may answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a serializable proxy library on the feign client and have made everything a spring component with a UIScope.

If this solution doesn't seem correct, please announce me! :)